# iOS State Restoration retrospection tool

Tags: ios

In the recent WWDC sessions focused on iOS State Preservation/Restoration, both have mentioned a command line tool which is meant to display all the saved state information in a human readable format. I can't find any documentation about this though, does anyone know what the program is called and how to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was searching for the same thing, found it on the [Apple Developer Downloads](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action) page (search for restoration). It's called the "restorationArchiveTool for iOS 7".

Put the tool in your path (in `~/.bash_profile`) and you can use it like this:

```
restorationArchiveTool --plist --structured -o ~/path/to/output.file ~/Library/Application\ Support/iPhone\ Simulator/{VERSION}/Applications/{HASH}/Library/Saved\ Application\ State/your.bundle.identifier.savedState
```